# std::numeric_limits as a Condition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, numeric-limits

Is there a way that I can use `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` and `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized` to change template behavior?

For example can I do this:

```
template < typename T >
void foo( const T& bar )
{
    if( std::numeric_limits< T >::is_integer )
    {
        isInt( bar );
    }
    else if( std::numeric_limits< T >::is_specialized )
    {
        isFloat( bar );
    }
    else
    {
        isString( bar );
    }
}
```

Comment: There are better traits to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "obvious" answer is that you could use something like `std::enable_if`.

For example:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, void>::type
    foo(const T &bar) { isInt(bar); }
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized, void>::type
    foo(const T &bar) { isFloat(bar); }
```

The problem with this approach is that this is ambiguous for (as an example) an `int` parameter, since [`numeric_limits<int>::is_specialized == true`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_specialized).

To resolve this, I would simply use a better trait than `numeric_limits`, personally. You can also use boolean conditions to test for the exact condition you want:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized && !std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, void>::type
    foo(const T &bar) { isFloat(bar); }
```

Comment: It looks like this would help if my functions varied by return type. I want them to vary by parameter type.

Comment: @Praetorian After understanding that the `std::enable_if` here was defining the return type as `void`, I tried this code out. I am able to get this to compile on VS2012. Perhaps I'm misusing @Rapptz's solution since I can't understand what the equality in the `template` parameters is doing.

Comment: @JonathanMee It's not equality, the `= 0` is the default template argument for the non-type template parameter of type `int`. BTW, trying to ping me in comments to other answers doesn't work. I only saw this because you linked to this question in your new question :)

Answer (score 8):

What you have is currently valid. However, you should prefer to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) instead since it would dispatch to a different function based on the type rather than rely on a branch condition (which may or may not be optimized away).

You can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to do the following:

```
template<typename T, 
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(const T& t) {
    isInt(t);
}

template<typename T, 
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(const T& t) {
    isFloat(t);
}

template<typename T, 
         typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value && 
                                 !std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(const T& t) {
    isString(t);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01f0edf095279d9c)

The reason that the second parameter for `enable_if` is set to `int` is to save us some typing. If the `int` is left out then we'd have to do `typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type` instead of just setting it to `0` which would save us a couple of characters to type. They're equivalent for all intents and purposes.

Comment: That second parameter to `enable_if` you always have as an `int`. I don't understand why.

Comment: @JonathanMee The `int` for the second parameter is there so you can set it equal to something (in this case `0`) that way you don't have to type `typename` redundantly, i.e. `typename = typename std::enable_if<condition>::type`

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly you'd probably want each of these `= 0` to be different (like `= 1`, `= 2`, and `= 3`) so you could reuse them in another method template?

Comment: @JonathanMee No, the condition just has to be different and unambiguous. You can set the number to whatever you want.

Comment: I'm on VS2012 when trying this: `template < typename T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral< T >::value, int >::type = 0 > void foo( const T& bar ){ isInt( bar ); }` but I'm getting the error: "error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template"

Comment: @JonathanMee The linked example compiles on VS2013. You should be able to get it to work on VS2012 if you move the `enable_if` expression to the return type of `foo`. And another alternative to using `int` within `enable_if` is `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr`

Comment: Why don't you just use `enable_if` to define the return type? It is much less typing that way (`template<typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type foo`…).