# How Does std::enable_if work?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enable-if

I just asked this question: [std::numeric_limits as a Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251380/stdnumeric-limits-as-a-condition)

I understand the usage where `std::enable_if` will define the return type of a method conditionally causing the method to fail to compile.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, void>::type foo(const T &bar) { isInt(bar); }
```

What I don't understand is the second argument and the seemingly meaningless assignment to `std::enable_if` when it's declared as part of the template statement, as in [Rapptz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381108/rapptz) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251380/stdnumeric-limits-as-a-condition/25251506#25251506).

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(const T& bar) { isInt(); }
```

Comment: (You are missing a `typename` in the second block of code you quoted.) `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type` is `int` if the value is `true`, so it declares a non-type template parameter of type `int` with a default value of `0`; if value is `false`, you get substitution failure so the overload is removed from consideration.

Comment: In order to understand how `std::enable_if` works you'll have to understand how [**SFINAE**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/SFINAE) works.

Comment: @T.C. so it's trying to do an assignment at compile time and *if* it is assigning to an `int` the assignment succeeds?

Comment: @JonathanMee [It's not assignment.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments)

Comment: Here is good explanation of enable_if, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html. It covers boost::enable_if, but std::enable_if works the same way.

Comment: @user763305 I've read through the boost documentation and it really helped me understand what's going down here. I was planning on writing a synopsis of it for an answer here as time permits. I will accept your answer instead though if you feel like writing a synopsis first.

Comment: I'm glad you found my comment useful. I don't have time to write a full answer; please go ahead and do it yourself.

Comment: @user763305 I've gone ahead and scribbled up an answer, I'll accept it in a couple days, if you think it could use clarification, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @T.C. Why, in the implementation of std::enable_if, the template parameter T is defaulted to void? Isn't it the same without?

Comment: @gedamial Yes in the case where the type returned will be `void`, the second template argument to `enable_if` may be omitted. The case I asked a question about illustrated passing a integral value, not a type, as a template argument. And defaulting that argument to 0. So given the function definition: `template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0> void foo(const T& bar) { isInt(); }` I could call this function like: `foo<int, 13>(1)` or `foo<int>(1)` in the latter case the second template argument would be defaulted to 0.

Comment: @JonathanMee thank for the answer. then why is it important, in the implementation of std::enable_if, that the parameter T is defaulted to void (in the case the bool Condition is false)?
If the condition is false, the function will be just hidden... there's no need to write `typename T = void`

Comment: @gedamial If you're intensely curious as to the motivation for defaulting it might warrant a follow up question. As it is though it does let us write things a bit more simply. For example I can rewrite my first example in this question to something as simple as: `template <typename T> enable_if_t<is_integral_v<T>> foo(const T& bar) { isInt(bar); }` If you do ask the question though, add a link here, if there were any good motivation rationales I'd like to read them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As is mentioned in comment by [40two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2352671/40two), understanding of [Substitution Failure Is Not An Error](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/SFINAE) is a prerequisite for understanding `std::enable_if`.

`std::enable_if` is a specialized template defined as:

```
template<bool Cond, class T = void> struct enable_if {};
template<class T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

The key here is in the fact that `typedef T type` is only defined when `bool Cond` is `true`.

Now armed with that understanding of `std::enable_if` it's clear that `void foo(const T &bar) { isInt(bar); }` is defined by:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, void>::type foo(const T &bar) { isInt(bar); }
```

As mentioned in [firda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25284593/2642059), the `= 0` is a defaulting of the second template parameter. The reason for the defaulting in `template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>` is so that both options can be called with `foo< int >( 1 );`. If the `std::enable_if` template parameter was not defaulted, calling `foo` would require two template parameters, not just the `int`.

---

General note, this answer is made clearer by explicitly typing out `typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, void>::type` but `void` is the default second parameter to `std::enable_if`, and if you have [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) `enable_if_t` is a defined type and should be used. So the return type should condense to: `std::enable_if_t<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer>`

A special note for users of [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) prior to [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013): Default template parameters aren't supported, so you'll only be able to use the `enable_if` on the function return: [std::numeric_limits as a Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251380/stdnumeric-limits-as-a-condition?lq=1#comment39343190_25251506)

Answer (score 10):

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(const T& bar) { isInt(); }
```

this fails to compile if `T` is not integral (because `enable_if<...>::type` won't be defined). It is protection of the function `foo`.The assignment `= 0` is there for **default template parameter** to hide it.

Another possibility: (**yes the `typename` is missing in original question**)

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(const T& bar) {}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
bar(const T& foo) {}

int main() {
    foo(1); bar(1);
    foo("bad"); bar("bad");
}
```

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(const char [4])’
  foo("bad"); bar("bad");
           ^
note: candidate is:
note: template::value, int>::type  > void foo(const T&)
 void foo(const T& bar) {}
      ^
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if’
 template::value, int>::type = 0>
                                                                                       ^
note: invalid template non-type parameter
error: no matching function for call to ‘bar(const char [4])’
  foo("bad"); bar("bad");
                       ^
```