# enable_if in template Parameters Creates Template Redefinition Error

Tags: c++, templates, typename, redefinition, enable-if

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28634468/2642059) what I really wanted to do is define a `typename` in my template parameters which could be used in the cast *and* return.

So this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto caster(T value)
  -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(T), unsigned char>::type
{ return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(value); }
```

Would become this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename R = std::enable_if<sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(T), unsigned char>::type >
R caster(T value) { return reinterpret_cast<R&>(value); }
```

This works and behaves as desired for a single template specialization, but say that I add another overload:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename R = std::enable_if<sizeof(short) == sizeof(T), short>::type>
R caster(T value) { return reinterpret_cast<R&>(value); }
```

Now I get an error:

> error C2995: 'R caster(T)' : function template has already been defined

Is there a way to convince the compiler that only one of these specializations will actually build for any given call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best solution here may be to use a slew of [`conditional`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/conditional/)s, which would prevent me from having to fool with template specializations:

```
template <typename T, typename R = std::conditional<sizeof(T) == sizeof(unsigned char),
                                                    unsigned char,
                                                    conditional<sizeof(T) == sizeof(unsigned short),
                                                                unsigned short,
                                                                conditional<sizeof(T) == sizeof(unsigned long),
                                                                            unsigned long,
                                                                            enable_if<sizeof(T) == sizeof(unsigned long long), unsigned long long>::type>::type>::type>::type>
R caster(T value){ return reinterpret_cast<R&>(value); }
```

My apologies to the reader cause it's like reading nested ternaries. However I'm currently unaware of a cleaner way to handle this.

This sadly still doesn't prevent the user from stomping on all my defaulting by providing his own second template parameter as mentioned by [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd).

**EDIT:**

I've asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680634/is-there-a-way-to-declare-a-typename-for-a-templatized-function?lq=1) which has a solution that doesn't require placing the `typename` in the template definition *and* doesn't require declaring the type twice.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Template default arguments are just that, *defaults*. Any user could call `caster<short, short>`, which would match both overloads.

However, it would be possible to add more dummy arguments.

```
template <typename T,
          typename R = typename std::enable_if<sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(T), unsigned char>::type >
R caster(T value) { return reinterpret_cast<R&>(value); }

template <typename T,
          typename R = typename std::enable_if<sizeof(short) == sizeof(T), short>::type,
          typename = void>
R caster(T value) { return reinterpret_cast<R&>(value); }
```

(Also note the added `typename`.)

---

However, since all bodies are identical, I probably wouldn't go with overloads.

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct cast_result;

template <>
struct cast_result<sizeof(std::uint8_t)> {
  typedef std::uint8_t type;
};

template <>
struct cast_result<sizeof(std::uint16_t)> {
  typedef std::uint16_t type;
};

...

template <typename T, typename R = typename cast_result<sizeof(T)>::type>
R caster(T value) {
  return reinterpret_cast<R&>(value);
}
```

A final note: this use of `reinterpret_cast` is a violation of the aliasing rules. However, that's easily fixed:

```
template <typename T, typename R = typename cast_result<sizeof(T)>::type>
R caster(T value) {
  R result;
  std::memcpy(&result, &value, sizeof result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah, well at least I understand why it's not building now. Seems like I could setup a `typedef` or something that wouldn't be a user parameter, but would define the type for use.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors on the `reinterpret_cast`? It certainly makes sense to me that it should work as-is. If the bit count is the same there shouldn't be a problem with treating one as the other?

Comment: @JonathanMee The language could have been defined that way, but wasn't. The standard contains: "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:" followed by a list that does not contain any notes on objects of a particular size. Some compilers (like GCC) use that rule to aggressively optimise code, noting that e.g. given `int *a` and `long *b`, code that stores to `*a` and reads from `*b`, the compiler can re-order the accesses since the pointers are not allowed to point to the same object.

Comment: @JonathanMee If you compile with `gcc -O2 -Wall`, you'll get a warning about it: "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules". (Note: that warning is trivially suppressed, but don't be fooled into thinking that code that does cause that warning is free of aliasing violations.)