# Is There a Way to Declare a typename for a Templatized Function?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, typename, function-templates

So, I have [this templatized function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28679275/2642059) (which I know is ugly to look at.)

My intention was not to default the template parameter though, my intention was to create a `typename` derived from `T` that could be used in `caster` that the user could not assign to.

My question is how do I create a `typename` for a templatized function which the user cannot pass as an argument?

As an example:

```
template <typename T>
typename R = std::conditional<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>;
R foo(T bar){return R(bar);}
```

Clearly this code doesn't compile, but that's the behavior I'd like to accomplish. Is a functor the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++14, this is elegantly solved using return type deduction.

```
// C++14
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
decltype(auto)
foo(T bar)
{
  using R = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>;
  return static_cast<R>(bar);
}
```

In C++11, you'd have to repeat the type computation.

```
// C++11
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>::type
foo(T bar)
{
  using R = typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>::type;
  return static_cast<R>(bar);
}
```

This can be shortened a little by using `decltype` to figure out the type.

```
// C++11
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>::type
foo(T bar)
{
  using R = decltype(foo(bar));
  return static_cast<R>(bar);
}
```

But frankly, what is wrong with using a simple default type parameter?

```
// C++11
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,
          typename R = typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>::type>
R
foo(T bar)
{
  return static_cast<R>(bar);
}
```

Note that I have replaced the value initialization of `R` in your `return` statement with a `static_cast` to silence the compiler warning about the narrowing conversion.  Are you sure that this is what you want, though?

Comment: @JonathanMee Since C++11, you can use `template<typename T, typename U> auto foo(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u) { return t + u; }`.  This is a *trailing return type* but no *return type deduction*.  Since C++14, you can also use `template<typename T, typename U> decltype(auto) foo(T t, U u) { return t + u; }` which is merely syntactic sugar but really great for reducing redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `using` type alias instead of `typename`. The following code compiles on the compiler I tested (remember to enable `-std=c++11` flag).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// C++11
template <typename T>
using R = typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>::type;

template <typename T>
R<T> foo(T bar){return R<T>(bar);}

int main() {
  std::cout << foo(13.0) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In C++14, you can use the `conditional_t` trait, which is even simpler.

```
// C++14
template <typename T>
using R = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) == 4, char, short>;
```

Comment: It works, but I don't like this solution very much because it introduces a new global name.  If this `R` template is useful in its own right, then this is a fine solution but if it's only to save some typing with the function declaration, I'd be reluctant to globally introduce a new type name.  Definitely not one with such a common / short name.  Putting the helper type in its own namespace could help mitigate the problem a little.

Comment: @YingXiong I am unable to get this to work on Visual Studio 2013 or gcc 4.92. Just putting this in `main` as test code should fail: `std::cout << foo(13.0) << std::endl;` gcc says: "error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'"

Comment: @JonathanMee You are right, what I had before failed to compile with your test case, sorry. I update my answer to fix the issue -- basically you should `using` the `::type` of `std::conditional` trait, not the trait itself. Please also note @5gon12eder's comment above, which I totally agree.