# Metaprogramming construct that returns underlying type for an enum and integer for an iteger

Tags: c++, templates, enums, metaprogramming, type-traits

I need to write a metaprogramming construct, that when given an enum type, it returns an underlying type of that enum, but when given an integer, it returns that integer.

For example:

```
enum Enum : short { VALUE1, VALUE2 };

int_type<long>::type  // -> long
int_type<Enum>::type  // -> short
```

I attempted this

```
template< typename Type >
struct int_type {
    using type = typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<Type>::value, typename std::underlying_type<Type>::type >::type;
};
template< typename Type >
struct int_type {
    using type = typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<Type>::value, Type >::type;
};
```

but it complains about redefinition of the struct.

I also tried this, but

```
template< typename Type >
struct int_type {
    using type = typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<Type>::value, typename std::underlying_type<Type>::type >::type;
    using type = typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<Type>::value, Type >::type;
};
```

but then it complains about redefinition of member `type`.

This is where my metaprogramming skills end, can anyone help?

EDIT: I should have also mentioned, that our project is limited to C++11.

Comment: Do you care if `int_type<std::string>::type` exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enable\_if in template Parameters Creates Template Redefinition Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674543/enable-if-in-template-parameters-creates-template-redefinition-error)

Comment: @Caleth I would prefer if it didn't.

Comment: @RaymondChen It's not duplicate. His problem is slightly simmilar but not the same, and his solution doesn't solve my problem optimally.

Comment: Sorry. Was trying to find a duplicate (because this comes up often) and picked a bad one. If you strip out the bodies, you'll see that you declared `template<typename T> struct int_type;` twice. You'll either need to reduce to one declaration, or make the two declarations different somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with partial specializations.

```
// primary template
template< typename Type, typename = void >
struct int_type {
};

// partial specialization for enum types
template< typename Type >
struct int_type <Type, typename std::enable_if< std::is_enum<Type>::value >::type > {
    using type = typename std::underlying_type<Type>::type;
};

// partial specialization for integral types
template< typename Type>
struct int_type <Type, typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<Type>::value >::type > {
    using type = Type;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0L8GpXlcZiu8Mb9e)

Comment: +1 beat me to it. This is a good answer since it ensures that int_type will not exist for anything other than integral types and enums.

Comment: Nice. It doesn't make much difference but I'd use inheritance, and combine the primary template and specialization for integral types: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MSwJ9HaCxRumtkgB

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your attempts is that you're defining the same thing twice, and although *part* of it uses `enable_if` that doesn't make the entire enclosing definition disabled when the `enable_if` isn't true. i.e. you have two definitions of `int_type::type` even when one (or both) of those definitions is invalid.

What you're looking for is [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template< typename Type >
struct int_type {
    using when_enum
      = std::underlying_type<Type>;
    using when_integral
      = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Type>::value, Type>;
    using type
        = typename std::conditional< std::is_enum<Type>::value,
            when_enum, when_integral
            >::type::type;
};
```

Or in C++14 and later:

```
template< typename Type >
struct int_type {
    using when_enum
      = std::underlying_type<Type>;
    using when_integral
      = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Type>::value, Type>;
    using type
        = typename std::conditional_t< std::is_enum<Type>::value,
            when_enum, when_integral
            >::type;
};
```

But I think I'd probably write it as an alias template:

```
template< typename Type >
  using int_type = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_enum<Type>::value,
    std::underlying_type<Type>,
    std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Type>::value, Type>>;
```

And maybe simplify it further and make `int_type<T>` an alias for the actual type, so you don't need to say `typename int_type<T>::type`:

```
template< typename Type >
  using int_type = typename std::conditional_t<
    std::is_enum<Type>::value,
    std::underlying_type<Type>,
    std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Type>::value, Type>>::type;
```

(N.B. In C++17 you can use `std::is_enum_v<Type>` and `std::is_integral_v` instead of saying `is_xxx<Type>::value`.)

Comment: I accepted the other answer, because it gives invalid type for a type that is neither enum nor integer. But thank's for showing me std::conditional.

Comment: I've added a version that does that, still using `conditional`

Comment: I have 2 suggestions:  
first keep `int_type` as a `struct` and add something like `static_assert(std::is_enum_v<Type> || std::is_integral_v<Type>, "int_type error: Type must be an enum or integral type");` to have a clear message error, you can then define an `int_type_t` alias if you want to.  
Then, replace `std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Type>::value, Type>` with `type_identity<Type>`, since you no longer need to check if `Type` is an integral type (you can find an implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) until C++20 is available)

Comment: I couldn't make the last version work in VS 2017. Still complains about the last `::type`.

Answer (score 0):

```
template< typename Type >
struct int_type {
    using type = typename std::conditional< std::is_enum<Type>::value, typename std::underlying_type<Type>::type, Type >::type;
};
```

Will do the trick. It is possible to chain std::conditional to choose different types/generate errors.