# Why Doesn't reinterpret_cast Force copy_n for Casts between Same-Sized Types?

Tags: c++, casting, binary, copy, reinterpret-cast

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), `reinterpret_cast`:

> Converts between types by reinterpreting the underlying bit pattern.

But wait, that's a lie cause it only works in these cases:

> When a pointer or reference to object of type `T1` is `reinterpret_cast` (or C-style cast) to a pointer or reference to object of a different type `T2`, the cast always succeeds, but the resulting pointer or reference may only be accessed if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types and one of the following is true:
>
> - `T2` is the (possibly cv-qualified) dynamic type of the object
> - `T2` and `T1` are both (possibly multi-level, possibly cv-qualified at each level) pointers to the same type `T3`
> - `T2` is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of the dynamic type of the object
> - `T2` is an aggregate type or a union type which holds one of the aforementioned types as an element or non-static member (including, recursively, elements of subaggregates and non-static data members of the contained unions): this makes it safe to cast from the first member of a struct and from an element of a union to the struct/union that contains it.
> - `T2` is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of the dynamic type of the object
> - `T2` is `char` or `unsigned char`

According to that list an illegal example would be:

```
auto foo = 13LL;
auto bar = reinterpret_cast<double&>(foo);
```

So the only acceptable way to make that cast is to copy the memory:

```
auto foo = 13LL;
double bar;

copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo), sizeof(foo), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bar));
```

My question is, why doesn't `reinterpret_cast` handle that for me? Or is there something else available so I don't have to jump through this hoop?

Comment: I believe that the first question should be: why do you want to do this reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Lol, well initially I realized I'd done something wrong here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28634468/2642059 But after my mistake I really just wanted to understand how to handle this situation properly.

Comment: Why not just use `memcpy` instead of `reinterpret_cast<char*>` and `copy_n`? If a byte-wise copy it appropriate use `memcpy`, if it isn't then your `copy_n` doesn't work either.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Please tell me more, why would I preffer `memcpy` to `copy_n` shouldn't that be essentially the same thing?

Comment: Because `memcpy` takes `void*` so you don't need the ugly `reinterpret_cast`, because if `foo` is `const` you don't need to remember to cast to `const char*` since `&foo` just does the right thing, because `memcpy` is very heavily optimised and you aren't relying on the implementation treating `copy_n` of `char` objects the same way, because it's easier to read and the conventional way to say "copy these bytes from here to here", etc. etc. I look at that `copy_n` and think "WTF is that doing?"

Comment: @JonathanMee: If I have a pointer which I know identifies an object of type `Foo`, but I need code to treat the underlying storage as though it were a type `Bar`, would it make more sense to say "Treat this code as a potential indirect access to a `Foo`" or "Treat this code as a potential indirect access to all objects of all types".  Having a compiler treat a reinterpret_cast of a pointer as the former would avoid the need to have the programmer code the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why doesn't `reinterpret_cast` handle that for me?

One reason is that the size, alignment, and bit representations aren't specified, so such a conversion wouldn't be portable. However, that wouldn't really justify making the behaviour undefined, just implementation-defined.

By making it undefined, the compiler is allowed to assume that expressions of unrelated types don't access the same object, which can allow better optimisation. For example, in the following:

```
int   & i = something();
float & f = something_else();

const int i1 = i;
f = 42;
const int i2 = i;
```

the compiler can assume that `i1` and `i2` both have the same value (`i` being unchanged by the assignment to `f`), and optimise them into a single constant. Breaking the assumption will then cause undefined behaviour.

> Or is there something else available so I don't have to jump through this hoop?

Copying the bytes is the only well-defined way to reinterpret one object type as an unrelated type.

Aliasing with `reinterpret_cast` or a union might work sometimes (assuming the size etc. match), but might trip you up if the optimiser gets too clever with undefined behaviour.

Comment: This answer only pertains to `reinterpret_cast` of references or pointers, not of number values. Given that the copying code in the question is seen as a solution, and given that all it does is reinterpret the value bits, I think this answer does not address the specific issue at all. But it's fine as an answer to the separate issue of pointer/reference reinterpretation restrictions (which my answer did not address).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't know what you mean. The question asks why pointer/reference casts are only allowed when they point/refer to related types; which I've answered. Numeric conversions (which, for `reinterpret_cast`, means conversion between a numeric value and a pointer) have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: The OP's examples reinterpret a `long long` value as a `double` value. Then he asks, "why doesn't reinterpret_cast handle that for me". This answer doesn't address that issue. It's not obvious. One of the people instrumental in creating C++ once inadvertently wrote a `reinterpret_cast` of number values, in a Usenet posting. (Only a handful of people ever saw it, because I sent it back with a note. ;-) ).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I feel like I'm missing something that might be important. what do you mean by: "`reinterpret_cast` of number values?" I wanted to know why i can't do a bitwise-cast between to primitives of the same size. In my understanding this answers that?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: By my reading of the question, there's no confusion over what `reinterpret_cast` does, and whether it converts values or references (assuming that's what you mean). It's simply asking why there are restrictions on which pointer/reference types can be converted. I believe I've answered that.

Comment: @JonathanMee: The “two primitives of the same size” in your examples, are `long long` and `double` (assuming a common implementation where they are indeed of the same size, usually 64 bits each). These are not pointers, they are number values. Mike's answer only concerns pointers and references, a bit of indirection, where there other issues.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf These are number values it's true, But I am using `reinterpret_cast` to treat `foo` as a reference, and in my mind that's what the this answer is addressing.

Comment: @Jonathan Well, in both examples the effect you implement (or attempt to implement) is copying the bits from a `long long` to a `double`. You then ask why `reinterpret_cast` doesn't support "that". That led to me to mis-interpret what you meant to ask about, sorry. But anyway, note that the main reason for the so called strict aliasing rule, explained by Mike in this answer, is not a reason for `reinterpret_cast` not supporting reinterpretation of a `long long` value as a `double` value. Reinterpretation of `long long` as `double` could (unsafely) have been supported regardless of that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "Mike's answer only concerns pointers and references" - no, my answer covers access to the aliased object through the reference/pointer obtained by the cast. That's what's not allowed (giving undefined behaviour), and (by my reading) is what the question is about. But this weird argument is getting so long and tedious I'm tempted to just delete the answer and pretend it never happened.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly the restrictions on `reinterpret_cast` (not fully captured by the cppreference site) are because of

- alignment issues and
- trap representations.

For a hypothetical `reinterpret_cast` to number value, different sizes can easily be handled by truncation or zero-extension, since one is into dangerous bit-level territory anyway, so that's not an issue.

By using `memcpy` or `copy_n` you work around the alignment issues, but you are still possible victim of trap representations. That means that use of the resulting value might blow up. On some platforms, for some values.

---

Note that the standard's guarantees about anything, can be and usually are extended by any particular compiler.

Often it can be a good idea to aim for just a little less portability than what you can have by relying solely on the standard.

For example, things get complicated fast when you can't assume that a byte is 8 bits. Making this assumption reduces portability. But still the set of supported platforms is large.

Comment: Ugh, so are you saying that even my work around won't necessarily work? As in there is *no* way to deterministically make this cast?

Comment: Different sizes can't be handled, since the result of a cast is a pointer or reference to the aliased type that knows nothing about the "real" type of the object. All it can do is treat whatever's in memory as an object of the aliased type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Context is sort of important when discussing things. We're discussing why `reinterpret_cast` doesn't handle reinterpretation of values of integers and floating point types. For this, "the result of a cast is a pointer or reference" would be incorrect (if such casts were supported).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You may be right, as I see the OP has used cast to reference. Fixing the wording.

Comment: @JonathanMee: You can make the cast, but depending on the original bits, you may, on some platform, end up with a trap representation. Which may cause mayhem just by being assigned. Still, *on a given set of platforms* (which can be pretty large) the cast can be safe. Note that with the `reinterpret_cast` that we have, where you have to convert to pointer or reference, and back, the sizes should better match. Value-based `reinterpret_cast` of non-pointers is just not supported.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf OK, so if I'm tracking you correctly, the answer to my question is: "`reinterpret_cast` doesn't do a `copy_n` for me cause handling all possible system alignments was a burden not imposed on compilers by the standard." and "I just have to use `copy_n`, it's not guaranteed, but there's nothing else out there."