# Copying from vector into a struct in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ 11, what is the best way to perform the following code:

```
// definitions
vector<char> rcvbuf; 

 struct somethingParams
{
  char Magic[4]; 
  int Version; 
  int MsgID; 
  int MsgLen;
};
```

Code:

```
struct somethingParams mParams; 
memcpy(&mParams, rcvbuf.data(), sizeof(somethingParams)); 
rcvbuf.erase(rcvbuf.begin(), rcvbuf.begin + sizeof(somethingParams));
```

From what I've read, memcpy is not recommended in C++. I understand that it is "C-style". Is there a better way to achieve what I am doing above? (ie. Copying data from a vector into a struct.)

Just see-ing if I can make it more "C++".

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately when it comes to copying things out of type unsafe buffers I don't there isn't really a much cleaner way to do this. One think to note is that in C++ you don't need the struct keyword.

Comment: Depends on the struct definition. If you're copying into an array member of a struct, then [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) is fine (and will handle non-POD types that `memcpy` won't). If you're trying to initialize sequential named members in the `struct`, you're already on the road to Hell, and your good intentions are just getting you there faster.

Comment: Have a look at [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/?hl=en), there're more about comms -- but you could use them to copy back-and-forth a `struct` to a `vector<char>` in a platform independent way

Comment: This is illegal: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28697626/2642059 You can `reinterpret_cast<char*>` but otherwise your going to run into aliasing problems.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the structure looks like exactly. I don't think the usage of `memcpy` makes it C++ style; it comes from C. Also what does `vector` contain ?

Comment: So it is a vector of chars, but the struct is taking a char array of length 4, did I see it right? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: If you want to move direction C++ I suggest using the string class for strings. Is there a reason you did not choose that way?

Comment: The data is being passed over the network from a source that uses c-style code. So at my end, I am interpreting it back into a struct.

Comment: I imagine. But do you realize that the vector has `n` elements of chars and the struct has a char array of length 4 and 3 ints? What are you trying to achieve when copying the vector data into the struct *blindly* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memcpy` is kosher in C++. Of course it should not be used to make a copy of an array (we have `std::copy` for that, as well as vectors and other fun things) but the case of initializing a struct from binary data is inherently type-unsafe so C++ doesn't give you anything here that C doesn't.

You must, however, remember to use `memcpy` only with trivially copyable types. You can use a `static_assert` to make sure you don't run afoul of this rule and trigger undefined behaviour.

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<somethingParams>::value,
              "somethingParams must be trivially copyable");
```

Comment: And you should `assert` or `static_assert` the size of your struct and integer byte order. And you should declare it with the necessary packing pragmas. Otherwise on the next change to integer size or alignment rules your code will break in invisible ways. Worst case you ship it and find out later the data files are incompatible with the old x86 version and then you have to add crazy hacks to try to detect which struct variant is in the file.

Comment: This is only available newer versions of C++11, though? I don't see it on my compiler. @ZanLynx how do I assert/static_assert integer byte order?

Comment: Won't endianness still be an issue here?

Comment: @NeilKirk Hi, it will be an issue if the two systems are of different endian-ness. In my case, both sides are the same. If say the network header is big endian, I would have to convert it to the native endian-ness.

Comment: @Ippier It's part of C++11. If your standard library doesn't support it, you might need to upgrade it... but an implementation without it is not a conforming hosted implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing. You have a `vector` of `char`s (of length `n` let's say) on the one hand.

And you have a struct with a `char` array of length 4 and three `int`s.

I don't see what a *blind* `memcpy` would bring as a reasonable result really.

But maybe I can evoke some thoughts that could help you dig further:

1. A `vector` of `char` elements could maybe replaced by a `string` object? A `string` object is meant to hold a `char` array internally. I consider this more C++, but depends on your requirements.
2. `memcpy` simply copies memory. I am not sure if this is what you want; I reckon the struct contains garbage after the copy. Unpredictable in my opinion.
3. To copy from a container (a `vector` is an STL container) a standard way of doing it in C++ (apart from the aforementioned [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) function) is by iterating over the elements and copy them. See below.

---

Most familiar with iterators:

```
for (vector<char>::iterator it = rcvbuf.begin(); it != rcvbuf.end(); it++) {
    //copy element *it into something
}
```

---

C++11 introduced auto range for loops:

```
for (auto elem : rcvbuf) {
    //copy element elem into something
}
```

---

Further elaboration:

The vector contains 16 elements. The 4th element is the null character to simulate the end of the C style string. Without the null character the `char` array would contain garbage too.

I removed the `erase` for simplicity. It simply erases the elements in a specified range (by iterators); in your case it simply removes `sizeof(somethingParams)` bytes/`char`s from the vector, provided it contains enough elements, otherwise segmentation fault is likely.

See the result below, it's plain nonsense.

```
char t[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'};
vector<char> rcvbuf(t, t + 16);

struct somethingParams {
    char Magic[4] = {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int Version{99};
    int MsgID{99};
    int MsgLen{99};
} mParams;


memcpy(&mParams, rcvbuf.data(), sizeof(somethingParams));
//rcvbuf.erase(rcvbuf.begin(), rcvbuf.begin() + sizeof (somethingParams));

cout << "Magic:   " << mParams.Magic << endl;
cout << "Version: " << mParams.Version << endl;
cout << "MsgID:   " << mParams.MsgID << endl;
cout << "MsgLen:  " << mParams.MsgLen << " bytes" << endl;
```

Result (with `int` occupying 4 bytes on my machine):

```
Magic:   abc
Version: 1734763876
MsgID:   1802135912
MsgLen:  1869507948 bytes
```

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on (2)? Why would the struct be garbage after the copy?

Comment: The memory alignment of a struct is `char,char,char,char,int,int,int` - and it is even possible that for optimization the memory alignment is changed. Copying from the *data*  of the vector is like copying from array, since `vector` aligns data contiguously. The `vector` consisting of `char` elements would be copied blindly into the memory of the `struct`. The struct would have the first four `char`s correctly, but the last three `int`s would contain garbage since you copy `char`s into that memory zone.

Comment: I tried to clarify in my answer, but I cannot help it. You have to ask yourself what you want to achieve (reasonably).