# What is the meaning of unsigned u = *(unsigned*)&x; in c++ where x is a float variable?

Tags: c++, floating-point, numerical-methods, unsigned

Since my Numerical Analysis course exam is near, I was searching for a implementation code to to represent floating point numbers in C/C++? Then I found a line from one the codes in github. Can you please tell me, what is the meaning of the second line in the code snippet below, and how and why this is important?

```
float x = ...;
unsigned u = *(unsigned*)&x;
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. What is `x` ? Almost all platforms use IEEE 754 to represent floating point numbers see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: It's impossible to tell why one line of code is important when there is no context at all. The line of code could be completely unimportant for all anyone can tell.

Comment: Written with C++ casts this would be `unsigned u = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned*>(&x);` i.e. the compiler is forced to ignore the fact that `&x` has type `float*` and interpret it as `unsigned*`. If you want to inspect the binary representation, I'd recommend an `reinterpret_cast` to `uint8_t*` to inspect the memory representation byte by byte. (Treat the result of the cast as if it would point to the first element of a array `uint8_t[sizeof(x)]`)

Comment: [Dereferencing the address of a pointer-casted variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56074903/995714), [Why cast to a pointer then dereference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39312058/995714)

Comment: It interprets the memory occupied by `x` as if it contains an `unsigned` instead of a `float`.  It also formally gives undefined behaviour.  On particular platforms it might be meaningful.   For example, if an `unsigned` is 32-bit and a `float` is 32-bit (that's not guaranteed with all compilers)  `u` and `x` will often end up containing the same sequence of bits/bytes in memory - but that sequence of bits has different meaning if interpreted as an `unsigned` than if it is interpreted as a `float`.

Comment: That snippet looks like a bad (i.e., **undefined behavior**, via type punning and big hammer casting) way to do `static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(unsigned)); float f = 123.0f; unsigned u; std::memcpy(&u, &f, sizeof u);`

Comment: It says "let's pretend that the memory named `x` actually represents a value whose type is `unsigned int`'. Like all make-believe games, it may or may not correspond to reality.

Answer (score 6):

`unsigned` is just short for `unsigned int` and using C++-style casts the line would translate to

```
unsigned int u = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&x);
```

However read below why this causes undefined behavior in either case.

(I recommend to not use C-style casts as in the line shown in the question, since it is not obvious to which C++-style cast they resolve.)

If `x` is a `float` variable, then the line is trying to reinterpret the object representation of the `float` variable as the object representation of an `unsigned int`, basically to reinterpret the `float`'s memory as the memory of an `unsigned int`, and then stores the `unsigned int` value corresponding to that representation in `u`.

Step for step, `&x` is a pointer to `x` of type `float*`, `reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&x)` is a pointer to `x`, but now of type `unsigned int*`. And then `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&x)` is supposed to dereference that `unsigned int*` pointer to the `float` variable to retrieve an `unsigned int` value from the pointed-to memory location as if the bytes stored there represented an `unsigned int` value instead of a `float` value. Finally `unsigned int u =`  is supposed to use that value to initialize `u` with it.

That causes undefined behavior because it is an aliasing violation to access a `float` object through a `unsigned int*` pointer. Some compilers have options which can be enabled to allow this (under the assumption that `float` and `unsigned int` have compatible size and alignment), but it is not permitted by the standard C++ language itself.

Generally, whenever you see `reinterpret_cast` (or a C-style cast that might resolve to a `reinterpret_cast`), you are likely to cause undefined behavior if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

---

Since C++20 the correct way to do this without undefined behavior is using `std::bit_cast`:

```
float x = /*...*/;
auto u = std::bit_cast<unsigned>(x);
```

or before C++20 using `std::memcpy`:

```
float x = /*...*/;
unsigned u;
static_assert(sizeof(u) == sizeof(x));
std::memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof(u));
```

The size verification is done by `std::bit_cast` automatically. Even without C++20 it would probably be a good idea to wrap the `static_assert` and `memcpy` in a similar generic function for reuse.

Both of these still require that the representation of `x` is also a valid representation for a `u`. Otherwise the behavior is still undefined. I don't know whether there even is any C++ implementation where this doesn't hold for all values in the `float -> unsigned` case.

---

Also as an additional note: C is a different language. The rules may well be different in C. For example there is obviously no `reinterpret_cast` in C to which the `(unsigned*)` cast could resolve and the object model is very different. In this case though, C's aliasing rules will have an equivalent effect.

Comment: Perhaps a note about *dereference that `unsigned int*` pointer to the float variable to retrieve its value as a `unsigned int`*: it's not the value of the float, but its bit representation taken as `unsigned int`.

Comment: @j6t Maybe its clearer now, I hope.

Comment: no, it's not "idiomatic" because it invokes UB: [Is reinterpret_cast type punning actually undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53995657/995714), [Is this type punning well-defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38000599/995714). The only valid way to type pun in C++ is via `std::bit_cast`

Comment: @phuclv Yes, I explain later that this causes undefined behavior. I put a note at the beginning to make it clear.

Comment: user17732522, Another pitfall: `unsigned` and `float` are not certainly the same size.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "_(under the assumption that float and unsigned int have compatible size and alignment)_": That's why I mentioned it with regards to extensions such as `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid C++. The behavior (of the **program**) is undefined.
The cast expression would cause the alignment requirement to be violated (aka "strict aliasing violation").
See: [§6.7 Memory and objects](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj), and [§6.8 Types](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types) of [ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/draft.pdf).

The problem is the [explicit cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) will become a `reinterpret_cast`:

```cpp
float boat = 420.69f;
// unsigned dont_do_this = * reinterpret_cast<unsigned *> (&boat);
//          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
//  Dereferencing `unsigned*` pointer which doesn't point to an `unsigned`.
```

`float*` is not [Pointer-Interconvertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#pointer-interconvertible) with `unsigned*`.
You could do this, instead:

```cpp
auto since_cpp20 = std::bit_cast<unsigned>(boat); // include <bit>
// Alternatively:
unsigned since_c;
std::memcpy(&since_c, &boat, sizeof since_c);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `x` is `float`, then the code is a hacky way to access the binary format of a float by copying its bits directly to an integer, i.e. without doing the normal floating point to integer conversion that would happen if you just wrote `u = x;`