# Is a struct with a one byte alignment safe to use a byte array

Tags: c++, memory, c++14

Is `struct alignas(1) byte {};` safe to use for allocating an arbitrary amount of bytes, and pointer arithmetic? I've preferred using this byte type over a char array since byte needs to be casted to another type to be used.

Quick example of use:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct alignas(1) byte {};

class Any
{
    byte* mData;
public:
    template<class T>
    explicit Any(T pValue) : mData(new byte[sizeof(T)]) {
        std::memcpy(mData, &pValue, sizeof(T));
    }

    ~Any() {
        delete[] mData;
    }

    template<class T>
    auto get() -> T& {
        return *(T*)(mData);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    Any a(i);
    std::cout << a.get<int>() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(mData);` (where `T` is `int` in this case) is undefined behaviour - your compiler may have an extension to make it implementation defined you will need to check.  Replace reinterpret_cast with std::memcpy to fix.

Comment: Hint: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte

Comment: @RichardCritten I'll change it to a regular c cast `*(T*)(mData)`

Comment: Look-up what a regular C cast does it's still UB. see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast .   You used memcpy to put the value into the array, you need to use memcpy to get it out.

Comment: what you call a "regular" cast isnt any better and the c++ cast should be prefered

Comment: I've given you a +1, I don't know why everything gets downvoted on here. Most of us have asked a question similar to this at 1 point in our careers. Mine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28697626/2642059 I've tried to answer why this is illegal in C++ in my answer. Note that that is in contrast to C, in which this is legal behavior. The problem is C++'s type aliasing rules. Which in most cases give it a speed advantage over pure C code, but here they are fighting against you :(

Comment: @RichardCritten memcpy wouldn't work there, because I'd like to return a reference to that int right? It looks like what I'm trying to do is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot allocate 4 bytes and then consider the address of the first to be the address of a 4-byte object because there may be alignment requirements.

There are for example hardware platforms in which accessing a 4-byte integer at an address that is not a multiple of 4 is a segfault, not just a performance problem.

Comment: I didn't know about this. Would allocating an array of `unsigned char a[4]` and casting it to a 4 byte integer also cause a segfault on the hardware you mentioned?

Comment: @Brian: yes, a char array (both as local or as a global variable) is NOT guaranteed to be aligned for other data types. You need to allocate an `int` or an `int[]` if you want to get an address that is for sure correctly aligned for `int`s. Another option is to use `malloc` that on the other hand guarantees an address valid for the most stringent data type.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I just found out about strict aliasing rules.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a C-Style cast in the line: `return *(T*)(mData)`. [C-Style casts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions)

> Converts one type to another by a mix of `static_cast`, `const_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`

So because `const_cast` and `static_cast` cannot cast between unrelated types this line equates to: `return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(mData)`

This code accesses the result of a `reinterpret_cast`, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) requires that, given `DynamicType` is `byte` and `AliasedType` is `T`, [1 of the following must be true](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing):

> - `AliasedType` is (possibly cv-qualified) `DynamicType`
> - `AliasedType` and `DynamicType` are both (possibly multi-level, possibly cv-qualified at each level) pointers to the same type
> - `AliasedType` is the (possibly cv-qualified) `signed` or `unsigned` variant of `DynamicType`
> - `AliasedType` is an aggregate type or a `union` type which holds one of the aforementioned types as an element or non-static member (including, recursively, elements of subaggregates and non-static data members of the contained unions): this makes it safe to obtain a usable pointer to a `struct` or `union` given a pointer to its non-static member or element
> - `AliasedType` is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of `DynamicType` and `DynamicType` is a standard-layout class that has has no non-static data members, and `AliasedType` is its first base class
> - `AliasedType` is `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes

If `T` meets one of those specifications then your code is uninteresting cannot convert from one type to another, but it is legal. If it's not, then your code introduces undefined behavior, and should be considered toxic.