# Pass a Failing Template Argument

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, undefined, enable-if

[Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828279/dan)'s answer to this question: [Is There Anything Like a Templatized Case-Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28699281/2642059) takes a `DefaultType` template parameter.

Is it possible to pass something there which will force a compile time fail?

For example, given this templatized function:

```
template <typename T, typename R = enable_if_t<is_integral<T>::value, int>>
R foo(T bar) {return static_cast<R>(bar);}
```

This code will compile fine: `foo(13)` But this code will fail: `foo(13.0)`.

The reason that `foo(13.0)` will fail at compile time is that `enable_if_t` is undefined. Is there a name for "undefined" that I can pass to the afore mentioned `DefaultType`?

If so I should be able to test this by calling `foo<int, undefined>(13)` and having it fail, if in fact `undefined` was the type I'm looking for.

**EDIT:**

Apparently more explanation is called for.

[Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828279/dan)'s `static_case can be called like this:

```
template<class T>
typename static_switch<sizeof(T),
                       int, // default case
                       static_case<sizeof(char),char>,
                       static_case<sizeof(short),short>,
                       static_case<sizeof(long),long>,
                       static_case<sizeof(long long),long long>>::type foo(T bar){ return reinterpret_cast<decltype(foo(bar))&>(bar);}
```

I want to pass "undefined" or whatever to that second parameter to make it fail to compile *only* when that parameter is evaluated. (The parameter marked "default case".)

In my simple test passing any two parameters to `foo` will succeed (for example `foo<int, int>(13);`) I want a parameter that would mimic the effect of `enable_if_t` causing it to fail (like when we call `foo<double>(13.0);`) In the example I said call `foo<in, undefined>(13)`. I just want to know what "undefined" is.

Comment: You may use Raymond Chen's answer to have the default case (which is the version non specialized of the template).

Comment: @Jarod42 What are you saying that I could pass here? `foo<int, struct matching_type{}::type>(13);`

Comment: If you specify `R`, you no longer use SFINAE. I'm not sure what you want to obtain exactly though.

Comment: @Jarod42 If you look at `DefaultType` that's what is "fallen through" to if none of the other cases matched. I want to achieve a fail there without adding Dan's last edit: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28699568/4

Comment: I've read the original question, then yours about three times, and I still can't figure out what you're asking. Do you want `13.0` to fail? Do you want `13.0` to work? Some code demonstrating what you want to work, what you want to fail, and how you want it to fail would be great.

Comment: @MarkB I have attempted to clarify, [Drax](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1147772/drax) seems to have the right answer. Perhaps his comment would be helpful in understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724017/pass-a-failing-template-argument?noredirect=1#comment45739879_28724605

Comment: The linked answer has been edited to manage your case by introducing `struct fail_on_default {};`

Comment: @Jarod42 Right, that's what I was trying to avoid. By using being able to pass "undefined" as the default argument I am able to preserve the functionality that *can* be defaulted if that is desired later in my program.

Comment: @JonathanMee:  `fail_on_default` is just a *special* default type, you still may use valid default type if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to have the `undefined` type you are talking about is:

```
std::enable_if_t<false>
```

So you can call your `foo` template like this:

```
foo<int, std::enable_if_t<false>>(13)
```

And have it fail as you asked.

Comment: Well I'm glad you get it. This is probably the correct answer. Anything I should have written up there that would have made it clearer for you?

Comment: @JonathanMee Yeah, the `undefined` type is actually not a type. It is a template expression that cannot be evaluated because you seek something that doesn't exist, if it was a dynamic language like javascript sure it would be `undefined` but in a statically typed compiled language like c++ it's wrong to even refer to it as an `undefined` type and it should rather be seen as an `non evaluable` template expression.