# Overloading template by Return Type

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, return-type, specialization

[Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck) makes a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769788/does-c-have-a-standard-compile-time-type-container#comment45821264_28769788) that "One function can't return multiple types. However, you can specialize or delegate to overloads, which works fine."

I started thinking about that, and I'm trying to figure out, how is this legal code:

```
template <typename T>
T initialize(){ return T(13); }
```

When called with:

```
auto foo = initialize<int>();
auto bar = initialize<float>();
```

Doesn't that translate to 2 functions of the same name overloaded by return-type only?

Comment: No. One function is named `initialize<int>`, and the other is named `initialize<float>`.

Comment: @JonathanMee I meant that `T initialize() {if (T==int) return 0; if (T==string) return "HI";}` isn't going to fly.  One function body can't have multiple types really.  To do anything interesting, you have to use complicated tricks

Comment: @MooingDuck Ah, thanks for clarifying I was beginning to wonder. Yeah I think that behavior would be contrary to the whole `template` idea anyway. Something like `T initialize() {return T(13);}` probably does make sense though.

Comment: If you are interested there are a few other ways to achieve the goal of two functions with the same signature but different return types.  1.) You can use namespaces and each function in a different namespace.  2.) You can make the function static methods and put each in separate classes.  Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @user3282085: I would recommend delegation instead, which allows the best of both worlds.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Could you elaborate how that would look with a small example or link?

Comment: .@Ela782: Honestly, I can't recall what I meant. I assume I meant to prefer overloads when possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an overload, it's a specialization.  They are different mechanisms (in fact mixing the two can lead to confusion, because overloads are resolved before specializations are considered -- see this Sutter's Mill article for example: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of the disallowed return value only overload:

```
int initialize();
float initialize();
```

OTOH, given the primary template definition

```
template <typename T>
T initialize(){ return T(13);}
```

Quoting from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)

> In order to compile a function call, the compiler must first perform name lookup, which, for functions, may involve argument-dependent lookup, and for function templates may be followed by template argument deduction. If these steps produce more than one candidate function, then overload resolution is performed to select the function that will actually be called.

`initialize<int>` and `initialize<float>` are simply two different instantiations of the said template. They are two different functions and would not be part of the same list of potential overload resolution candidates.