# C++14 using alias for is_same::value

Tags: c++, templates, helper, c++14, c++17

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28633312/2642059) uses `is_same<uint64_t, decltype(val)>::value`.

I expected there to be a C++14 `using alias`: `is_same_v` similar to the helper types: `conditional_t`, `enable_if_t`, and `tuple_element_t` which I use in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28634468/2642059). Because the only thing I ever use any of those functions for is to get the `type`. So the `*_t` helper just makes sense.

Which brings me to my question, why is there no `using alias is_same_v` in C++14? The only thing I use `is_same` for is it's `value`. Perhaps the usage of `is_same` is not typically for template declarations?

Comment: `is_same<T, U>::value` is not a type.

Comment: @Wintermute: There is still template variable.

Comment: Yes, but how would you have a helper type that's not a type? Also, you can usually just use `std::is_same<T, U>()` because of the `operator bool`.

Comment: @Wintermute Right, I got that, I'm not asking for `is_size_` **`t`** I'm asking for `is_size_` **`v`**. Similar to the way the helper type `enable_if_t` is defined: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Helper_types

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<cond, T>` is a type, you'll notice. No type, no type alias. You could, I suppose, build a `constexpr` function to be called as `std::is_same_v<T, U>()`.

Comment: I think you mean "using alias" not "helper type", as `is_same_v<...>` wouldn't be a type, as that would be pointless.  :)

Comment: @Yakk I've edited cause you're totally right. Looking at all the comments that's what confused everyone, I was just using the wrong terminology. I wish I'd have recognized this 2 days ago!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is_same_v` (and other `*_v` type traits) have been proposed by [N3854](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3854.htm). They didn't make into C++14 but they are in the [Library Fundamentals TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3908.html#meta.type.synop).

One of the concerns was a potential overlap with the [Concepts Proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3889.pdf) which might offer a better alternative for type traits (and many other current meta-programming techniques). An outdated but clearer explanation of Concepts can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

#### Introduction

The primary reason for introducing `std::enable_if_t<cond, T>` as a shorter form of`std::enable_if<cond, T>::type` is not to shave of a mere count of *4* characters.

Since `std::enable_if`, and other *type-traits* of its kind, is mostly used in dependent contexts, it is quite painful having to write *(A)* when *(B)* would suffice:

<sub>**Example**</sub>

```
template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if<cond, T>::type> // (A)
struct A;
```

```
template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<cond, T>>              // (B)
struct A;
```

---

---

#### Dependent Names

We need *typename* prior to `std::enable_if` because `::type` is a *dependent-name*, and without it the Standard says that the expression shall be parsed as if `::type` is actually a *value*.

`std::is_same<T, U>::value` is really a *value*, so there's no need for the use of *typename*; which in turns mean that we are effectively shaving of a mere count of 4 characters.. nothing more.

<sub>**Further Reading**</sub>

- [stackoverflow.com - **Where and why do I have to put the *template* and *typename* keywords?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101297/1090079)

---

---

#### So,  why isn't there a *variable-template* for *std::is_same*?

Simply because there isn't that big of a need, so no one did propose the addition in time; as *most* are satisfied with the below alternatives:

```
std::is_same<T, U> {} == std::is_same<T, U>::value
std::is_same<T, U> () == std::is_same<T, U>::value
```

<sub>**Further Reading**</sub>

There is a [proposal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3854.htm), written by *Stephan T. Lavavej*, to add variable-templates for the suitable *type-traits*.

- [open-std.org - **N3854** - Variable Templates For Type Traits](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3854.htm)

Comment: Note that `is_same<T,U>{}` does `==` `std::is_same<T,U>::value` but only through an implicit conversion.  In comparison, `is_same<T,U>{}()` is actually of type `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that the primary reason for introducing the `_t` helpers was to get rid of the need for putting `typename` everywhere. When you use a type trait such as `conditional` or `tuple_element` in the context of a template so that it depends on a template parameter (which is a *very* common use case), you have to prefix the construct `std::conditional<X, Y, Z>::type` with `typename`. You don't have to do that with the `_t` helpers, because they aren't nested in something which depends on template parameters.

You don't have to add any such prefix for `std::is_same<X, Y>::value`, because the memeber `value` is not a type.

Second, how would you introduce a helper *type* for a *value,* anyway? The best you could do is a variable template. Since it would only save typing `::value`, instead of `typename /*...*/ ::type`, it was probably deemed unnecessary.