# std::enable_if predicated on std::is_convertible not deducing template correctly

Tags: c++, enable-if

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if
                                 <std::is_convertible<int, T>::value, T>::type>
void func(T a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if
                                 <!std::is_convertible<int, T>::value, T>::type>
void func(T a)
{
    a.print();
}

class Test
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    }
};    

int main()
{
    func(3);
    func("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

With this code, I expected the first call to `func` to print out `3` (as `int` is indeed convertible to `int`, the first specialization should be called) and the second call to `func` to print out `Test` (`Test()` is not convertible to `int`, so the second specialization should be called). However, I instead get a compiler error:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> prog.cpp:27:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘func(int)’
>
> prog.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: template [class T, typename std::enable_if[std::is_convertible[int, T>::value, T>::type  > void func(T)
>
> prog.cpp:5:6: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> prog.cpp:27:8: note: couldn't deduce template parameter ‘[anonymous>’

If, however, I change the templated functions to instead be (while leaving everything else exactly the same):

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if
                                 <std::is_convertible<int, T>::value, T>::type* =
                                  nullptr>
void func(T a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if
                                 <!std::is_convertible<int, T>::value, T>::type* =
                                  nullptr>
void func(T a)
{
    a.print();
}
```

then everything compiles and works as I expected. What is this extra syntax doing and why do I need it?

Comment: duplicate of [How Does std::enable\_if work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284499/how-does-stdenable-if-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<int, T>::value, T>::type>
```

if we were to remove the noise, would become

```
template<typename T, typename Something<T>::type>
```

which is declaring as its second parameter a non-type parameter, the `typename` here is specifying the nested `type` is a name of a type. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923369/when-is-the-typename-keyword-necessary) for more information.

In the first case, the second parameter is non-type, so the function call `func(3)` doesn't fit the template which is expecting `func<int, some_int>(3)`.

Comment: @downvoter kindly explain, I am intrigued as to why this is perceived as downvote worthy

Comment: You haven't answered the question. I noted in the question itself that providing a default parameter of `nullptr` solved the issue - why is the default parameter required?

Comment: @R_Kapp I replied with the first three sentences. Everything below is added because I assumed you aren't familiar with SFINAE.

Comment: The template parameter would result in a syntax error with or without the default argument correct (if the boolean in `std::enable_if` is `false`)? How does adding the default argument change things?

Comment: I.e., instead of `template <Test, ???* = nullptr>`, it would be `template <Test, ???>`?

Comment: @R_Kapp Yes, but then your template wouldn't fit with the function call

Comment: Why does `std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<int, T>, T>::type`, which should convert to `std::enable_if<true, int>::type` for `T = int`, and then to `int` not fit the function call for `func(3);`?

Comment: @R_Kapp Because the second parameter is non-type, you'd have to supply it with a value like `func<42>(3);`, but since it is the second parameter, you'd have to write `func<int, 42>(3)`

Comment: To me, that last comment the answer in what I was not understanding with the syntax. That makes sense

Comment: @R_Kapp Yeah, I totally misunderstood