# Why does std::enable_if require the second template type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have the following function template

```
template
<
    typename FilterLHS,
    typename FilterRHS,
    typename Of = typename FilterLHS::OfType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Filter<Of>, FilterLHS> && std::is_base_of_v<Filter<Of>, FilterRHS>, int> = 0
>
std::shared_ptr<OrFilter<Of>> operator ||(const std::shared_ptr<FilterLHS> &lhs, const std::shared_ptr<FilterRHS> &rhs)
{
    return std::make_shared<OrFilter<Of>>(OrFilter<Of>{ lhs, rhs });
}
```

It works fine. My question is, why is the `int` second argument, and default value of `enable_if` required? As I understand, especially from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25363479/352552), I should just be able to do

```
template
<
    typename FilterLHS,
    typename FilterRHS,
    typename Of = typename FilterLHS::OfType,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Filter<Of>, FilterLHS> && std::is_base_of_v<Filter<Of>, FilterRHS>>
>
std::shared_ptr<OrFilter<Of>> operator ||(const std::shared_ptr<FilterLHS> &lhs, const std::shared_ptr<FilterRHS> &rhs)
{
    return std::make_shared<OrFilter<Of>>(OrFilter<Of>{ lhs, rhs });
}
```

but when I do that, my template never seems to get enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `enable_if` would go through, the first snippet would produce:

```
template<int = 0>
```

Which is valid.

But this, which is what you would get from snippet 2:

```
template<void>
```

Isn't and so SFINAE always kicks in here.

Comment: Hm - so it seems the linked answer is simply wrong to recommend dropping the default type?

Comment: @AdamRackis I don't think the linked answer is recommending such a thing. There are two different function templates being discussed in that Q&A. The `=0` is required for the one where `enable_if` is used in a template parameter, and the last paragraph in that answer is saying the one where `enable_if` is used in the return type can be written in a shorter way.

Comment: Basically, @AdamRackis, the version without a type parameter is valid in any context where `void` would be valid.  In your case, the `enable_if` parameter is a non-type template parameter, and thus cannot be of incomplete type `void`.