# How do I detect if anything but an integer is passed to my class constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, int, c++20, numeric-limits

***Fair and simple: How do I check if anything else but an integer is passed to my class in c++?***

If I pass f.e. a `char 'a'` my class gets number `97` in ascii.

I tried `std::numeric_limits` but I don't get why it is not detecting integers:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

class integerCheck
{
public:
    integerCheck(int value)
    {
       if((value != std::numeric_limits<int>::is_integer))
           return;

       std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    integerCheck valInt(88);
    integerCheck valChar('a');
    integerCheck valFloat(13.44f);

    return 0;
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251380/stdnumeric-limits-as-a-condition) Post working with `std::enable_if` but I can't imagine there is no way to detect wrong input even in c++20 but wrapping everything in a template.

***What am I missing, what should I look/search for to detect anything but an integer value?***
Thanks upfront

Comment: If an `int` object has a value 97, there is no special label or designation of any kind that tells you whether it's really the value 97, or 'a'. C++ simply doesn't work this way. It's 97. That's all you know.

Comment: Your use of `numeric_limits` is very confused—it’s checking the argument *value* (converted from whatever type) against a constant `true`.  More study is required.

Comment: @DavisHerring 'More study is required' on what part exactly. numeric_limits or templates? It is hard for me finding authors with the ability to explain abstract concepts for a simple mind like mine without linguistic encryption - like trying to put everything in 2 words so the reader (me) needs to unpack the whole sentences that the authors compressed/encrypted in 2 words.

Or in simple words, It is not easy for me to find authors that are confident enough to use simple descriptions without being afraid of writing simple words. But I keep searching - but maybe you got a tip where too look?

Comment: @Ivanovic: Calling it encryption is self-defeating: teaching is hard, and C++ is hard, but no one is *trying* to interfere with your education.  The additional study that I recommend is just the basic semantics of the language (see the usual book lists): the test you wrote operates at *runtime*, independent of the type of the argument expression, and so it just **can’t** be right.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks for answering so quick and the clarification. Ok it can't be right because the code operates at runtime. Why? (Honest question) In my experience teaching isn't hard and c++ isn't hard either but both is made hard, started with Bjarne Stroustrup who aimed c++ for being an academic discipline and millions of c++ students wasting lifetime in figuring out unnecessary over-complicated materials. But again - my opinion and I already working on fixing this gap.

Comment: @Ivanovic: If the test worked as you wanted, it would have to produce different results for `integerCheck(1)` and `integerCheck((char)1)`, right?  But those call the same function with the same parameter value, so how would that work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete the constructor taking `char`s and make the ctor `explicit` to prevent accepting `float`s as follows

```
class integerCheck
{
public:
    explicit integerCheck(int value)
    {

        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
    integerCheck(char ) = delete;
};
```

This doesn't allow the two following ctors to compile

```
integerCheck valChar('a');
integerCheck valFloat(13.44f);
```

I think the following will be better to prevent all of types except `int`.

```
class integerCheck
{
public:
    explicit integerCheck(int value)
    {

        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }

    template<class T>
    integerCheck(T ) = delete;
};
```

Notice that the past code doesn't prevent the est of the integral types like `long`, `size_t`, `short`, ...

Answer (score 5):

Your constructor takes only `int` values as input. A `char` is an integral type, so it is implicitly convertible to `int`. So are floating point types.

And your use of `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` doesn't work because it is true when `T` is `int`, like you are hard-coding. But it would also be true for other integral types too, including `char`.

If you want to avoid implicit conversions, you could pass the `int` by a non-const reference, eg

```
integerCheck(int &value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

However, that means you can't pass in integer literals, either. Only `int` variables.

A better solution is to make `integerCheck()` use a template parameter, and then you can check the type of the template that the compiler deduces from the input, eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
integerCheck(const T &value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

```
integerCheck valInt(88); // T=int
integerCheck valChar('a'); // T=char
integerCheck valFloat(13.44f); // T=float
```

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
class integerCheck
{
public:
    // Arguments of type other than `int` go here.
    template <typename T>
    integerCheck(T) {}

    integerCheck(int value) {
       std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
};
```